# Set global variable to be accessed from other files - javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global

I found the solution by using `global.consoleLog = v => this.log(v));`. Now the variable consoleLog is available anywhere.

#### ORIGINAL QUESTION

Currently I am participating in the battlecode challenge. My question is about Javascript though and accessing a global variable.

I have a minimal working example with two files.

```
// === robot.js === 
import { BCAbstractRobot } from 'battlecode';
import Test from './test.js';

class MyRobot extends BCAbstractRobot {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.log("asdf"); // the log function does work
        // Test.setConsoleLog(this.log); // way 1
        // console.log = this.log; // way 2
    }
    turn() {
        Test.testFunction("hello");
        return this.move(0, 1);
    }
}

// === test.js === 
let consoleLog = undefined;

function setConsoleLog(c) {
    consoleLog = c;
}

function testFunction(s) {
    // consoleLog(s); // way 1
    // console.log(s); // way 2
}

export default { testFunction, consoleLog, setConsoleLog };
```

Since battlecode gives you the log function, you cannot use console.log for security reasons. However I want to be able to log from any file. The log function is a property of the MyRobot class, but I want to be able to access the function from other files and functions without passing parameters every time.

I tried a couple ways. First I tried creating an export from a util file (test.js) which would start out as undefined and then be set by setConsoleLog. However, when I attempt to use consoleLog, it is still undefined.
I also tried overwriting the console.log reference, but this only works within one file and the reference is still to console.log in other files.

What would be the recommended way to go about creating a global reference or import to this.log such that any file could import it and access it?

The bot is run within a node vm, but with a bundler as far as I know.

Comment: Did you consider exporting said log function? So you could simply import it in other files... This would be more consistent with what you use anyways and even more importantly be cleaner code (Polluting the `window` object is considered bad practice.)!

Comment: The code is transpiled and I think there were issues exporting from the main file. I'm also okay with adding the log function to the global object because console.log would be available globally anyway and useful everywhere.